# Metro App Customised ListView Mouse Scroll

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a Metro application with a `ListView` that has this definition:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lvData" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" SelectionMode="Extended">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Padding="4,0,0,0">
                                <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=lvData, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                    </Grid>

                                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>

                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Once this `ListView` is filled, how do I Scroll this `ListView` with a mouse? Can't seem to work it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the mouse wheel? Also, if there is another control over it, that control may be intercepting and handling the PointerWheelChanged event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a control on the page that was constantly stealing focus through other events that were being triggered, as such this event was NOT being fired. Things are working well now.

Specifically, it was the `WebView` control. See this article for workaround:
[[WinRT Trick] Scrolling](http://blog.christopheargento.net/2013/02/07/winrt-trick-scrolling-and-webview-navigatetostring-bug/)